# Safety advice for best EMF detector and body shielding for UHF RFID reader

Tags: safety, rfid, emf

I've got a UHF RFID detector (860 to 960 MHz). I'm just getting into configuring the power output but I think I've been testing it at about 20dBM, I might want up to 30dBM. I'm concerned about my health when having it on beside me for extended periods as I test with it (I'm doing development on an embedded device connected to the reader).

I'd like advice on two things:

1. What to look for in an EMF detector that will help me gauge the strength of the radiation (I'd test it indoors/outdoors at various distances and angles). Links to products or terms to shop for would be awesome. I can buy from anywhere but I'm in Canada, FYI. If it's simple to build one with an Arduinio for example let me know and I can whip one up myself if there's a big cost advantage.
2. What to look for in body shielding. The two things that seem reasonably priced and the most practical are [these coveralls](http://www.lessemf.com/personal.html#366) and [this tent](http://www.lessemf.com/personal.html#718). The tent seems like it would be ideal though as I could just put my desk in there and come and go as I need to, keeping the equipment outside.

Thank you!

Comment: That site is a hoot!  I'm getting some EMI protecting undies, socks and gloves.  But seriously if I was worried about EMI that is the last place I would buy something from.  And what are you talking about 20dBm, 100mW that doesn't sound scary.

Answer (score 3):

From [the Wikipedia dBm article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm), there is a table with some examples of devices with different power levels:

> 33 dBm:
>
> - Maximum output from a UMTS/3G mobile phone (Power class 1 mobiles)
> - Maximum output from a GSM850/900 mobile phone
>
> 30 dBm:
>
> - Typical RF leakage from a microwave oven
> - DCS or GSM 1,800/1,900 MHz mobile phone. [...]
>
> 27 dBm:
>
> - Typical cellular phone transmission power

If cell phones are safe at these power levels when kept in pockets, I would not be worried about having your 20-30 dBm transmitter sitting on a desk nearby.